# Run a C# unittest only if another one passes

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

I'm trying to run a UnitTest in C#, but only if another UnitTest passes? Can't quite get it to work, does anybody know how I can do this?

Edit: It's in NUnit

Comment: In general, unit tests should be able to execute in any order, so there shouldn't be a dependency between them, however, you can pass data between them using the `TestContext` if you really have to.

Comment: *Why* do you require the tests to run in a certain sequence? If test B requires a specific configuration extract it in a separate test class and perform any setup steps in the `Setup()` method

Comment: You should not do that. Unit tests should be executed separatly.

Comment: This is the idea, I'm making a system that sends data to a localhost server. The first test will be wether every field is filled up. But if that fails, I shouldn't want to send that data to the server, that's why I want to do it in a specific oder

Comment: The ideia of unit test is to test each logic unit separatly. So, I think that in your case, there are two tests: (1) Test if the data is correctly constructed, (2) Test if, whatever data comes in, the data is sent. Separating this in two tests have benefits: If you make a code mistake, you will immediatly know if you broke the data construct method and/or if you broke how the data is sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountered this problem a while back. A solution I came up with may not be the most elegant but it works. What I did to get around the ordering issue is I created my own unit testing framework. It was propriety to the company I worked for so I can't share it with you.

In the testing framework, there existed

- A template for each type of test & a generic template to aggregate all the tests
- A utility to execute each template type

For example, if I was doing an integration test, I would have a "http utility" and the template would contain the endpoint & payload.

The tests I wanted to run would need to be stored into an intermediate data structure such as json. This allowed me to serialize the tests into templates.

Now this is where it gets tricky... Using some fancy T4 templating, I would get the json data & serialize it to a list of templates. Then I would order the tests by execution order and dependency (one test could be dependent on another for chaining integration tests). I would then generate a unit test for every template. The generated unit tests would then run on build

For your question about canceling test execution if one fails, you can build that into your templating using some fancy logic

```
static List<ITestTemplate> requiredTests = new List<ITestTemplate>();
...
if(requiredTests.Any(t => t.Failed))
  Assert.IsTrue(false) //fail subsequent tests
```

Answer (score 0):

You could accomplish this, though it may not be the cleanest solution, by using the [Order()] attribute. ([docs](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Order-Attribute))

This will allow you to run the dependency-test as [Order(1)] and the test relying on the first test as [Order(2)]. You can share your driver across the tests, and if the first test fails, close the driver, causing the other tests relying on the first test passing to fail.